# Force hide address bar in Chrome on Android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I recently developed a website that fetches mixed http/https content. Due to this, I always get the address bar displayed on top (It doesn't auto-hide like in other websites). Here's what I'm talking about:

[image: The Website]

[This](https://planetkde.org/) is the link to the website.

The content is fetched from various sources, hence filtering non-https content is not possible. And since the website is meant for reading, a non-full-screen display is painful for the reader. So, is there a way to force the auto-hide behavior?

PS: The website uses Twitter Bootstrap, if it helps.
PPS: I don't want to use the full-screen API, it'll be too heavy for this.

Comment: Can't block address bar... stop and think about it...if every site did that how would user access it?

Comment: I'm sorry if the question implied so, but I don't mean to block the address bar. So in Chrome for Android, the address bar auto-hides when you scroll down and pops back up when you scroll up. This behavior enables a user to enjoy reading in full screen while scrolling down.

Comment: @charlietfl like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/hpiFp.gif

Comment: What is impact if you serve from `http` protocol?

Comment: I think it would work. But I can't do so, I'm not the one handling the server.

Comment: @Ranveer: I noticed you fixed your Chrome bar issue, yet you have no accepted answer here... how did you fix it?

Comment: A better cross-browser solution is discussed at: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/fullscreen/

Answer (score 68):

Check this has everything you need

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/fullscreen/

The Chrome team has recently implemented a feature that tells the browser to launch the page fullscreen when the user has added it to the home screen. It is similar to the iOS Safari model.

```
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

Comment: what do you mean "add it to the home screen?

Comment: Found it, it was an option on the chrome menu.

Comment: Note that the user may not be able to restore the address bar afterwards if he wants to: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/55659/how-do-i-disable-full-screen-mode-in-chrome-for-android

Comment: I mean is it possible to hide the address bar without creating shortcut on home scree???

Comment: Now how do I get rid of the title bar across the top of the document that has the document name, URL, and three vertical dots to bring up the menu?

Comment: @MahaDev it is! read the article... you can do it with screenfull https://www.npmjs.com/package/screenfull

Comment: nice! This is possibly the coolest yet hardest thing to find on the internet lol OK maybe slight exageration... but HUNDREDS of posts saying "its not possible".... "JustWatch.com" is how I KNEW it was possible... Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

```
window.scrollTo(0,1);
```

this will help you but this javascript is may not work in all browsers

Comment: This hack does NOT work on Chrome 49 when the content height is less than the viewport. Tested on Stock Android 5.1.1 Galaxy S6 Edge.