# App which only opens Browser

Tags: php, android, jquery, html, ios

I made a simple Website which I want now to display also on the mobil devices.
So I want to make a App which only opens a browser without displaying the tab bar and the url bar. 
I want to do this for android and for iOS.

Does anyone knows good tools for that or can I programm this also with Html as a Web app??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force hide address bar in Chrome on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28647604/force-hide-address-bar-in-chrome-on-android)

Comment: Please use only really applicable tags.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a lot about IOS, but in Android you can create shortcuts of website pages in your homescreen and it might work.

About what you are asking, you can both use some cross-platform tool, like [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/). (I posted the most famous, I'm not here to explain which cross-platform tool is the best one, there are enough questions for this). Btw with Cordova you can build your own application using html, css, js.

Now, if you want something native, simply check a tutorial on how to create a webapplication([android official guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)).

It's pretty simple and doesn't require that much skill.

**Note#1:** I think I have to tell you an economic note: publishing is not free, for example `IOS` costs around **100$/year**. So consider if you really want do build an app only displaying a website. It's a more common and (**imho**) a best way of doing things, building a complete application with all buy, ... tools. Usually people dislike webapp if they can see the exact same thing with the mobile browser.

Usually apps gives something more than a simple website.

**Note#2:** I don't know if [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) allows you to build an app showing only a website, you should inform

**Note#3:** you should move your question, this community is for code, if you want some hint look for google or other platforms, there are a lot of "how to" on the net :)