# Encourage mobile browser to keep address bar hidden when input is focused?

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios, soft-keyboard

I'm aware of the general [strategies for hiding the address bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28647604/force-hide-address-bar-in-chrome-on-android), e.g. encouraging installation as home screen app and/or sometimes [scrollTo hacks](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/fullscreen/#fake_it_auto-hide_the_address_bar). In my case, however I am fine with the default behaviors. As the user navigates my app, the browser tends to eventually hide the scroll bar and that's fine.

My problem is, users need to do a lot of text editing in my app. When this happens, especially in landscape mode, the soft keyboard can take up tons of the visible screen but to make matters worse, the bar tends to re-appear! On top of over half the screen getting taken up by the keyboard itself, an additional 1/5th or so gets suddenly eaten back up by the address/tab interface even if it had gone away.

So I'm left with a tiny strip that the user can see, for no apparent reason.

I suspect this is a long shot, but is there any way to discourage these tabs from re-appearing? To be clear, the user is **not** trying to edit the URL, but has simply focused in an `<input>`/`<textarea>` to edit *that*.