# Manifest not loaded to remove address bar

Tags: android, google-chrome, manifest.json

I'm trying to get rid of the address bar on the top of my web app when viewed on Chrome mobile.

I have "installed" it on Chrome Mobile by "Add to Home Screen".  This gets rid of the "address" bar in a useless way - it replaces the address bar by an almost identical sized bar with the name of the web page, a big blank space where the address bar would be, and the three dots on the right to bring up a Chrome menu.

So now I've got almost the same problem.  How do I get rid of this pseudo address bar?  In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28656938/543873) it mentions creating a link to a manifest.   There is also documentation on this on [Google's own documentation page](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/fullscreen/), under "Chrome for Android" so I assume it should know what it's talking about and "just work".

My manifest looks like this:

```
{
    "short_name": "Test",
    "name": "My Test Web App",
    "start_url": "/app/test",
    "display": "standalone",
    "orientation": "landscape"
}
```

However, I see absolutely no difference.  In fact, when I look at the page in the developer tools, it doesn't even appear that the manifest is being used.  I have confirmed there isn't a caching issue, as I see the correct tag in the `HEAD` of the source:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
```

This doesn't work either on HTTP or on HTTPS (although the cert has expired and I haven't gotten around to updating it yet).  It also doesn't seem to work on Chrome on the desktop either.

Update: I updated Chrome Mobile from v87 to v89 and for some reason now it can see the manifest. I also managed to get landscape mode to work by removing the shortcut on the home screen and re-adding it.  But it *still* shows the large title bar at the top of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the updates, something about updating Chrome mobile to a couple versions newer caused it to discover the manifest.

To get the bar at the top of the screen to go away I had to renew my SSL certificate.  This is apparently an undocumented "feature" to display info about the page if Chrome thinks it's not secure.